# Formula to calculate the number of days I need to take off from work for a trip

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some Google Sheets data which looks like this:

| Trip | Departure | Time | Ret. Dep. | Return Arr. | Arr. Time | Biz Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DR | 30-Jul-2016 | 11:04 | 06-Aug-2016 | 06-Aug-2016 | 20:47 | 5 |
| IT | 19-Jan-2017 | 22:20 | 02-Feb-2017 | 02-Feb-2017 | 19:00 | 10 |
| NO | 22-Jul-2017 | 22:05 | 04-Aug-2017 | 04-Aug-2017 | 18:25 | 10 |
| FR | 18-Dec-2017 | 20:30 | 01-Jan-2018 | 01-Jan-2018 | 18:45 | 8 |
| IS | 25-Jul-2018 | 20:25 | 05-Aug-2018 | 05-Aug-2018 | 20:30 | 7 |
| ES | 25-Dec-2018 | 23:00 | 06-Jan-2019 | 06-Jan-2019 | 21:00 | 7 |
| AU | 17-Apr-2019 | 18:40 | 04-May-2019 | 05-May-2019 | 17:37 | 12 |
| UK | 20-Jul-2019 | 18:00 | 03-Aug-2019 | 03-Aug-2019 | 19:20 | 10 |
| TR | 25-Dec-2019 | 0:30 | 04-Jan-2020 | 04-Jan-2020 | 12:55 | 6 |
| PE | 23-Apr-2022 | 11:27 | 06-May-2022 | 07-May-2022 | 15:24 | 10 |
| CH | 05-Aug-2022 | 16:25 | 19-Aug-2022 | 19-Aug-2022 | 14:25 | 10 |
| IN | 22-Apr-2023 | 11:55 | 05-May-2023 | 06-May-2023 | 07:35 | 10 |
| MX | 30-Jul-2023 | 7:55 | 03-Aug-2023 | 04-Aug-2023 | 00:41 | 4 |

Given the departure day, departure time, return arrival day and return arrival time, I'm trying to calculate how many days between this I need to take off from work under the column "Biz Days". ("Biz Days" currently show the manually calculated correct values, not from the formula.)

The following are the requirements:

- If the departure time is on or after 3:30 PM then I don't need to take that day off because I'm already done with work for that day.
- If the return arrival time is on or before 7:00 AM, then I don't need to take that day off because I can go to work straight from the airport.
- If the departure or arrival is on a Saturday or Sunday, then obviously I don't need to take that day off anyway
- A set of pre-defined company holidays are in a different sheet in this range - "Hols!$A$2:$A$1001", so I don't need to take off these days

I have the following formula which only takes into consideration the departure times and for that, it works fine. But I need to enhance the formula to also consider the arrival times, but I haven't been successful.

```
=IF(AND(OR(WEEKDAY(B14,2)=1, WEEKDAY(B14,2)=2, WEEKDAY(B14,2)=3, WEEKDAY(B14,2)=4, WEEKDAY(B14,2)=5), COUNTIF(Hols!$A$2:$A$1001,B14)=0, C14>TIME(15,30,0)), NETWORKDAYS(B14,E14,Hols!$A$2:$A$1001)-1, NETWORKDAYS(B14,E14,Hols!$A$2:$A$1001))
```

For example, this is something I tried, but doesn't work:

```
=IF(AND(
    OR(WEEKDAY(C15, 2)=1, WEEKDAY(C15, 2)=2, WEEKDAY(C15, 2)=3, WEEKDAY(C15, 2)=4, WEEKDAY(C15, 2)=5),
    COUNTIF(Hols!$A$2:$A$1001, C15)=0,
    E15>TIME(15, 30, 0),
    K15>=TIME(7, 0, 0)
  ),
  NETWORKDAYS(C15, I15, Hols!$A$2:$A$1001) - IF(K15<TIME(7, 0, 0), 1, 0),
  NETWORKDAYS(C15, I15, Hols!$A$2:$A$1001) - 1
)
```

FWIW, ChatGPT and Bard also were not able to solve this.

Here's the actual spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15vbYbH__qrblQhxXXfKcJ7TuDpRQNB9HmOkEWbqFwPY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your example columns do not match your formula columns. Do share a test sheet.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to update the "Biz Days" cells with the values for a successful outcome.

Comment: @marikamitsos Sorry about that, fixed it. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're making this too hard.  This is just Networkdays function with a possible exclusion of the endpoint days.  So if you need to exclude the departure then add one to the date and if you need to exclude the return then subtract one from the return date, like this:

```
=max(0,NetWorkDays(B15+if(C15>=Time(15,30,0),1,0), E15 - if(F15<=Time(7,0,0),1,0), Hols!$A$2:$A$1001))
```

Comment: @marikamitsos Thanks. I had tried upvoting it before, but I got the error that I don't have the 15 reputation points threshold to do so. I didn't know about accepting the post, but just figured it out and did so, and magically after that I could upvote as well.

Answer (score 0):

When formulas get this complicated, I split them into helper columns. They're easier to create, debug, and maintain. If you need the formulas in a single column for your finished product, combine the formulas into one column once you get them working.

Two things first **(all addresses here are based on your Google sheet, not on your formulas, and I've done this in Excel, not Google sheets)**:

- You can simplify the day of the week from `OR(WEEKDAY(B2, 2)=1, WEEKDAY(B2, 2)=2, WEEKDAY(B2, 2)=3...` to `WEEKDAY(B2, 2)<=5` (no need to compare to each day)
- Exclude day if "departure time is on or after 3:30 PM": don't you want `C2 < TIME(15,30,0)` instead of the `>` in your formula?

Taking both of those into account, splitting the formula into 3 columns (Leave, Return, Days in columns H, I, J) makes it simple. The Leave and Return columns determine the first and last days, based on your conditions. Then the NETWORKDAYS() is easy to work with:

H2: `=IF(AND( WEEKDAY(B2,2)<=5, COUNTIF(Hols!$A$2:$A$1001,B2)=0, C2<TIME(15,30,0)), B2, B2+1)`

I2: `=IF(AND( WEEKDAY(E2,2)<=5, COUNTIF(Hols!$A$2:$A$1001,E2)=0, F2>TIME(7,0,0)), E2, E2-1)`

J2: `=NETWORKDAYS(H2, I2, Hols!$A$2:$A$1001)`

Apologies, I can't seem to convert the Excel times to Markdown in this table, but even with those ugly decimals it still shows the process:

|  | **A** | **B** | **C** | **D** | **E** | **F** | **G** | **H** | **I** | **J** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Trip | Departure | Time | Ret. Dep. | Return Arr. | Arr. Time | Biz Days | Leave | Return | Biz Days |
| **2** | DR | 7/30/2016 | 0.461111111111111 | 8/6/2016 | 8/6/2016 | 0.865972222222222 | 5 | 7/31/2016 | 8/5/2016 | 5 |
| **3** | IT | 1/19/2017 | 0.930555555555555 | 2/2/2017 | 2/2/2017 | 0.791666666666667 | 10 | 1/20/2017 | 2/2/2017 | 10 |
| **4** | NO | 7/22/2017 | 0.920138888888889 | 8/4/2017 | 8/4/2017 | 0.767361111111111 | 10 | 7/23/2017 | 8/4/2017 | 10 |
| **5** | FR | 12/18/2017 | 0.854166666666667 | 1/1/2018 | 1/1/2018 | 0.78125 | 8 | 12/19/2017 | 12/31/2017 | 8 |
| **6** | IS | 7/25/2018 | 0.850694444444445 | 8/5/2018 | 8/5/2018 | 0.854166666666667 | 7 | 7/26/2018 | 8/4/2018 | 7 |
| **7** | ES | 12/25/2018 | 0.958333333333333 | 1/6/2019 | 1/6/2019 | 0.875 | 7 | 12/26/2018 | 1/5/2019 | 7 |
| **8** | AU | 4/17/2019 | 0.777777777777778 | 5/4/2019 | 5/5/2019 | 0.734027777777778 | 12 | 4/18/2019 | 5/4/2019 | 12 |
| **9** | UK | 7/20/2019 | 0.75 | 8/3/2019 | 8/3/2019 | 0.805555555555555 | 10 | 7/21/2019 | 8/2/2019 | 10 |
| **10** | TR | 12/25/2019 | 2.08333333333333E-02 | 1/4/2020 | 1/4/2020 | 0.538194444444444 | 6 | 12/26/2019 | 1/3/2020 | 6 |
| **11** | PE | 4/23/2022 | 0.477083333333333 | 5/6/2022 | 5/7/2022 | 0.641666666666667 | 10 | 4/24/2022 | 5/6/2022 | 10 |
| **12** | CH | 8/5/2022 | 0.684027777777778 | 8/19/2022 | 8/19/2022 | 0.600694444444444 | 10 | 8/6/2022 | 8/19/2022 | 10 |
| **13** | IN | 4/22/2023 | 0.496527777777778 | 5/5/2023 | 5/6/2023 | 0.315972222222222 | 10 | 4/23/2023 | 5/5/2023 | 10 |
| **14** | MX | 7/30/2023 | 0.329861111111111 | 8/3/2023 | 8/4/2023 | 2.84722222222222E-02 | 4 | 7/31/2023 | 8/3/2023 | 4 |

Comment: Thanks for the help, RichardCook. I didn't go to this length since Chris's formula worked beautifully.